# Is it bad to reuse other programmer's code libraries that can perform generic tasks?

Tags: programming-practices, libraries, code-reuse

Reusing large amount of helpful codes made by other programmers is very tempting for me. I specifically refer to codes that can perform generic tasks, such as Data Access Layer (DAL) codes.

I am just beginning a project using a newly familiar language, and I don't think programming from scratch is feasible. I can understand the semantics and many other concepts of  that language, it is just the case that maybe I'm too lazy to start over and wanted to dive in to the task of coding a specific business logic.

So given that using a code library of others is perfectly legal, is it bad to acquire a large portion of somebody's work and use it as a foundation of mine?